# Surface Integral using divergence theorem over unit sphere?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

Use the Divergence Theorem to compute the surface integral $\iint_T \vec{F}^{\,}* \,d\vec{S}^{\,}$ where T is the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $\vec{F}^{\,}$ $<x,y,z> = <y, z, x>$. I calculated the divergence of F to be 0 + 0 + 0 = 0. Does this mean that the surface integral is 0? I am confused by this result.

Comment: div F is 0, then the flux over a closed surface is 0.

Comment: Your result is right, and that is the reason why we use Divergence Theorem here as a "shortcut" rather than directly calculating the complicated integral.